# Button not showing in the UI

Tags: acumatica

I'm extending the AccountByPeriodEnq logic, I just want to add a button on top of my screen to modify the selected GL records but it just doesnt want to show up and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code :

```
namespace PX.Objects.GL
{
    class AccountByPeriodEnqExtensions : PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
    {
        #region Actions
        public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> Letter;
        [PXUIField(Visible = true, DisplayName = "Lettrer")]
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        protected virtual IEnumerable letter(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            IReadOnlyCollection<GLTranR> selectedTrans = GetSelectedTrans();

            if (selectedTrans.Any())
            {
                PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
                {
                    foreach(GLTranR line in selectedTrans)
                    {
                        // UpdateSomeFieldsAndPersists
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                throw new PXException("Error");
            }

            return Base.Filter.Select();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Utility
        private IReadOnlyCollection<GLTranR> GetSelectedTrans()
        {
            return Base.GLTranEnq.Cache.Updated
                .Cast<GLTranR>()
                .Where(tran => tran.Selected == true)
                .ToArray();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here ?

Regards,

Edit:

To clarify i'm trying to customize the GL404000, Account Details. And using the inspector I saw the Business logic is in the AccountByPeriodEnq Graph

Comment: Can you post your screen aspx ? If you customized it you should find it in your website CstPublished folder

Comment: I think you might have mismatch the Screen/BLC/DAC name, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: You should also double check if 'tran.Selected' is giving you the correct reading. I noticed 'Selected' is treated as a special case that doesn't fire events and update cache like other fields. I suspect it's a hardcoded performance hack but can't pinpoint where/why that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Acumatica Inspect Element feature notice that the 'Account by Period' screen (GL402000) is not using the 'AccountByPeriodEnq' graph.

It is using the 'AccountHistoryByYearEnq' graph instead so that's the graph you want to target:

[image]

You also need to declare Actions on the primary DAC of that Graph.

The one for 'AccountHistoryByYearEnq' is a little bit harder to find than usual.

You can use Acumatica Source Code page and search for 'PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(AccountHistoryByYearEnq)':

[image]

In this case it is AccountByYearFilter DAC that you should use:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[PXCacheName(Messages.Account)]
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(AccountHistoryByYearEnq), Filter = typeof(AccountByYearFilter))]
public partial class Account : PX.Data.IBqlTable, PX.SM.IIncludable
{
  […]
}
```

I think this is a special case for Filter, when there's no filter Account would have been the DAC to use for the Actions.

---

Now that you have identified the Primary Graph of the Screen (AccountHistoryByYearEnq) and the Primary DAC of the Graph (AccountByYearFilter) it should work as expected:

```
public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AccountHistoryByYearEnq>
{
  public PXAction<AccountByYearFilter> letter;

  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Letter")]
  [PXButton]
  protected virtual IEnumerable Letter(PXAdapter adapter)
  {
      return adapter.Get();
  }
}
```

UI:
[image]

---

**EDIT:**

For Account detail page (GL404000), use the same code with different DAC and Graph:

```
using PX.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace PX.Objects.GL
{
  public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
  {
      #region Actions
      public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> letter;

      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Letter")]
      [PXButton]
      protected virtual IEnumerable Letter(PXAdapter adapter)
      {
          return adapter.Get();
      }
      #endregion
  }
}
```

With a base Acumatica install that's all that is needed for the Action to appear:
[image]

Note that you can specify explicit state and view rights for the button control, though I don't think your issue is related to access rights if you're working in a developer instance:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Letter", 
           MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, 
           MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I'm trying to customize the GL404000 "Account detail" graph which has the AccountByPeriodEnq PXGraph.

Comment: I updated my question for that screen. If you're still having difficulty I suggest you start from the example I provided or double check every little detail like upper/lower casing and private/public access modifier. If you suspect your customization is not running with the latest changes consider iisreset or a new customization project with different namespace/class names to avoid conflicts.

Comment: hello thanks a lot, but I answered my own question, your are right it was the public access modifier. Anyway I learnt a lot from your answer so thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem, I missed the public member for my class.

```
namespace PX.Objects.GL
{
    public class AccountByPeriodEnqExtensions : PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
    {
        #region Actions
        public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> Letter;
```

Thanks for your answer HB, i'll reuse it.